# How to accept bad certificates on web client

Tags: flutter, ssl-certificate, flutter-web

With dart:io it is possible to use badCertificateCallback, like that:

```
httpClient.badCertificateCallback = ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);
```

But on the **web client**,  the dart:io is not available. I use http.dart library, but it does not provide the **badCertificateCallback** method.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

```
  class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides{
      @override
      HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context){
        return super.createHttpClient(context)
          ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port)=> true;
      }
    }
    
    void main(){
      HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
```

Comment: SecurityContext requires dart:io as well

Comment: Yep, this doesnt work. Initializing securityContext on web will throw error